# How to run parallel, asynchronous tasks in a non-blocking way inside a class in Python

Tags: python-3.x, asynchronous, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, python-asyncio

I am running an iterative main block of code, which now we can assume runs forever, say `loop A`.
After a given condition inside this loop is met, I want to spawn `N` asynchronous and parallel processes of another loop, say `loop B`. The code must not stop once these are launched. Then, at every next iteration, the code must check whether the results from `loop B` are available. If so, do some stuff, if not, just keep going with the `loop A` logics.

Everything is inside of a class object, which is run by a code driver.

I am implementing in Python 3.11, for Windows 11.

It reads as follows:

```
def MyClass: 

    def __init__(self, ):
    pass 

    def loop_A(self): 
        
        while True:
               
            ... do some stuff ... 
            if condition: 
               res_B = launch_pool_of_B_in_parallel(n_processes=N, args=([some_args[i]) for i in range(N))

            if res_B is done: 
               post_process(res_B)
            else:
               pass # go back to loop A
```

Now, it is my understanding that I should be able to do that using the `asyncio` module. However, I am struggling to run it in a non-blocking way. I managed to run it concurrently on another Thread (but not another process, unfortunately, as I ultimately would like), but it always stops `loop A`.

Specifically, I am launching `loop B` with the following helper function:

```
self.run_parallel_loop(self, func, args_):
     with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(n_jobs) as executor:
            loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
            tasks = [loop.run_in_executor(executor, func, *args_[i]) for i in range(self.n_jobs)]
            results = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
    return results
```

Then, in `loop A` I spawn `Loop B` as:

```
if not task_running:
   async_jobs = asyncio.create_task(self.run_parallel_jobs())
   results = []
```

and I would like to check the results with a logic like:

```
if len(results) < self.n_jobs:
   try:
       results_ = await asyncio.wait_for(async_jobs, timeout=0.1)
       results.extend(results_)
   except asyncio.TimeoutError:
       pass
   if len(results) == self.n_jobs:
      res_tmp = results # ready to post-process
      task_running = False # ready to launch again async processes
```

I am not reporting the errors because they vary according to my tentatives (in which I modify slightly the implementation): sometimes I receive `asyncio.exceptions.CancelledError` sometimes the loop never sees the results of loop B, some times it blocks the main loop A. Thus, it is clear that I am doing something wrong methodologically. Could you please help me out?

P.S.: for what concerns the Thread/Pool error, when I spawn `ProcessPoolExecutor` i get:`TypeError: cannot pickle '_io.BufferedReader' object` this I suppose it happens because when I spawn a new process they do not share the same memory, so to circumvent this I should create a `class LoopB`, right?

Answer (score 0):

I have several suggestions.

- When you post a question to StackOverflow, proofread it.  Your code contains indentation errors and inconsistent variable names.  The second listing is not even a function definition - I suspect a cut and paste error.  If you do this you will get better and faster answers.
- You might as well get rid of asycnio for this problem.  Loop B sends all your functionality to other threads anyway, so in your main thread there is no need for (and no benefit from) asyncio.
- There is enough functionality in `concurrent.futures` to do what you need without asyncio.  You could use a ProcessPoolExecutor instead of a ThreadPoolExecutor if your script is CPU-bound, but you must take care that `func` is accessible to a secondary Process.  If you have a problem with that, you should probably ask a different question.

One approach is to submit function calls to worker threads and collect the returned Futures in a list.  The list of futures can be checked to see if they are all finished; if so you go to post_process.

I suggest something like this:

```
def MyClass: 
    def __init__(self, ):
        self.results = []
        self.futures = []

    def loop_A(self):
        # In the next line, pick a number of worker threads
        # that gives good performance
        with ThreadPoolExecutor(10) as ex: 
            while True:
                ... do some stuff ... 
                if condition: 
                    # I don't know where the function and the
                    # arguments come from in your code
                    self.futures.extend(self.loop_b(ex, func, args_list))
                # Test to see if all the futures are done
                if all(fut.done() for fut in self.futures):
                    self.post_process()

    def loop_b(self, ex, func, args_list):
        # Submit calls to func, return all the futures
        return [ex.submit(func, a) for a in args_list]

    def post_process(self):
        # This is just a stub
        # but you should clear the futures list and
        # transfer the data to the results list somehow
        for fut in self.futures:
            self.results.append(fut.result())
        self.futures.clear()
```

I also see that you want to make sure the program keeps running, so you need to add exception handling.  In case of an error in a worker thread, fut.result() will raise an Exception.